# How to get the COUNT/frequency of the most frequent value(MODE) within the main group by query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery, common-table-expression

This is my query:

```
WITH subtable AS (
SELECT
    member_casual,
    seasons,
    start_station_name || ' to ' || end_station_name AS route
FROM
    bike_data
)

SELECT
    member_casual,
    seasons,
    MODE() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY route) AS most_frequent_route, 
    COUNT(*) AS total_service_used_count
FROM
    subtable
GROUP BY
    member_casual,
    seasons;
```

And this is the result:
[image]

The difficulty comes in when I want to include the frequency/count of the `most_frequent_route` as a new column in this groupby result. Before asking here, I asked a nice senior person before and he said:

> Put the main query into a CTE, then in the new outer query you can write a scalar subquery that performs the count over the subtable where the subtable rows match those from the grouping CTE.

Honestly I don't really understand the core logic of this advice, so I can't really put all of these together as a complete query. Can anyone give me some example how to make it work? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the nice senior person meant this:

```sql
WITH subtable_a AS (
SELECT
    member_casual,
    seasons,
    start_station_name || ' to ' || end_station_name AS route
FROM
    bike_data
),
subtable_b as
(
SELECT
    member_casual,
    seasons,
    MODE() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY route) AS most_frequent_route, 
    COUNT(*) AS total_service_used_count
FROM
    subtable_a
GROUP BY
    member_casual,
    seasons
)
select sb.*, 
(
  SELECT count(*) 
  from subtable_a sa 
  where sa.member_casual = sb.member_casual
  and sa.seasons = sb.seasons
  and sa.route = sb.most_frequent_route
) as most_frequent_route_count
from subtable_b sb;
```

Your `subtable` becomes `subtable_a`, your main query becomes `subtable_b` (Put the main query into a CTE) and in the new main (outer) query select all from `subtable_b` and a scalar subquery column - the inner capitalized `SELECT count(*)` in parentheses - that extracts `most_frequent_route_count`.

Comment: Thanks @Stefanov.sm , it works! I am definitely studying the core logic from this awesome answer so I can reapply the concept whenever a similar problem about subquery and CTE appears!

Comment: If I understand this query correctly, the reason to use `SELECT count(*) 
  from subtable_a sa ` is that I want to find out the count of routes, which only comes from the main table; and after that it is only a matter of applying conditions to shrink the main table size so that it fits the combination of `seasons`, `member_casual`, and the most_frequent_route that appear in subtable_b.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind.